# ToggleClass animate jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a section on my website that when a user clicks I would like it to expand, I'm using the jQuery's `toggleClass` for this...

```
expandable: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('article').toggleClass('expanded', 1000);
}
```

This is working fine, only I'd like to somehow animate it. In chrome my article slowly grows to the new size, only in Firefox it 'instantly' resizes itself with no animation, is there a way to have this animate?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

jQuery UI extends the jQuery native `toggleClass` to take a second optional parameter: `duration`

```
toggleClass( class, [duration] )
```

[Docs + DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/)

Comment: So if I want to animate/fade this action I have to use whole jQuery UI library?? Is there another way to do this without jQuery UI?

Comment: @ed1nh0, You can create a custom jQuery ui with only the pieces of what you need. [See here](http://jqueryui.com/download/), I must admit I have no idea in what category it should be in there.

Comment: To use animated toggleClass with jQuery UI, you have to load `Core` and `Effect Core`. See http://jqueryui.com/download/#!themeParams=none&components=1000000000000000000010000000000000

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Adding UI still is not working for me. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/jb_fresh/06bc8fwb/3/

Answer (score 26):

`.toggleClass()` will not animate, you should go for `slideToggle()` or `.animate()` method.

Comment: With slideToggle() can I set a min height so it doesnt hide completely?

Answer (score 20):

You can simply use CSS transitions, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj639rc6/)

```
.on {
color:#fff;
transition:all 1s;
}

.off{
color:#000;
transition:all 1s;
}
```

Comment: The best solution.  CSS animation and transitions can replace a myriad of (now) unnecessary JavaScript functions and actions and make code much lighter.  Nice one Dario

Answer (score 8):

I attempted to use the toggleClass method to hide an item on my site (using visibility:hidden as opposed to display:none) with a slight animation, but for some reason the animation would not work (possibly due to an older version of jQuery UI).

The class was removed and added correctly, but the duration I added did not seem to make any difference - the item was simply added or removed with no effect.

So to resolve this I used a second class in my toggle method and applied a CSS transition instead:

The CSS:

```
.hidden{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
}
.shown{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
    transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1.3s;
}
```

The JS:

```
    function showOrHide() {
        $('#element').toggleClass("hidden shown");
    }
```

Thanks @tomas.satinsky for the awesome (and super simple) answer on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826469/3129514)

Answer (score 6):

You should look at the `toggle` function found on [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).  This will allow you to specify an easing method to define how the toggle works.

`slideToggle` will only slide up and down, not left/right if that's what you are looking for.

If you need the class to be toggled as well you can deifine that in the `toggle` function with a:

```
$(this).closest('article').toggle('slow', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Brombomb, I'm currently using toggleClass() I was just unsure if I can add an animation to it too.

Comment: As a sidenote (because I didn't notice this at first), .toggle() allows you to animate the hiding or showing of an element in the DOM. I'd thought at first that it would animate the transition between class states, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Should have checked, Once I included the jQuery UI Library it worked fine and was animating...