# Toggle class with animation

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I want to have something like this :

```
$('#fo').toggleClass('tra', 'slow');
```

I know that i can achieve this with jQuery UI but i'm looking for a faster and smaller solution because i don't wanna integrate in my site another 20-90 kb

Comment: possible duplicate of [ToggleClass animate jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179238/toggleclass-animate-jquery)

Comment: @putvande this is no duplicate, OP says he does *not* want to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use `.animate()` instead. You'll need to animate the individual styles that you want changed. E.g. `.animate( { height: "500px", width: "200px" }, 2000 )` to change the height and width to those values over 2 seconds. jQuery UI lets you derive animations from class changes, pure jQuery doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery UI, you'll probably have to CSS3 transitions/animations that trigger at the right time (see http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-animations-trigger-right-time) or just `.animate` with  JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6YJVF/) (but it's not the cleanest):

```
function animateClass(el, klass) {
    var endCSS = el.toggleClass(klass).css();
    var startCSS = el.toggleClass(klass).css();
    for ( var p in endCSS ) {
        if ( startCSS[p] === endCSS[p] ) {
            delete endCSS[p];
        }
    }
    el.animate(endCSS, 'slow', function() {
        el.toggleClass(klass).removeAttr('style');
    });
};
```

It also assumes that you aren't going to add any other inline styles. Though I guess you could replace the animate callback with something like this:

```
for ( var p in endCSS ) {
    endCSS[p] = '';
}
el.toggleClass(klass).css(endCSS);
```

It also uses a plugin that extends the use of `$.fn.css` to return all CSS from [How can I get list of all element css attributes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471118/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-element-css-attributes-with-jquery#answer-1471256)

### Short Answer

CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the animation name as a third parameter.

```
$('#fo').toggleClass('big-blue', 'slow', "easeOutSine");
```

Comment: The question asks specifically how to do this _without using jQueryUI_, but the parameters used in this answer are exclusive to jQueryUI.