# How to easeout this animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to animate this animation during exact time. How to easing this animation.

```
$( "#slice1" ).click(function() {
  $("#post1").toggleClass("post"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about jquery UI you can use a second optional parameter to set the `duration`:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect" ).toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );
      return false;
    });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179238/toggleclass-animate-jquery)