# jQuery Animated Text Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get each letter color to swap from red to green and back to red.

What I have now works, but I don't like the fading, is there a better way to do this?

```
  const ltr = $('h1').text().split('');
  function colorChange() {
    $( 'h1' ).fadeOut(500, function() {
      redGreen();
    }).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500, function() {
      greenRed();
    }).fadeIn(500);
  }

  setInterval( function() {
    colorChange();
  }, 1);

  function redGreen() {
    $('h1').text('');
    for(var i = 0; i < ltr.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
        $('h1').append('<span class="red">' + ltr[i] + '</span>');
      } else {
        $('h1').append('<span class="green">' + ltr[i] + '</span>');
      }
    }
  }
  function greenRed() {
    $('h1').text('');
    for(var i = 0; i < ltr.length; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
        $('h1').append('<span class="green">' + ltr[i] + '</span>');
      } else {
          $('h1').append('<span class="red">' + ltr[i] + '</span>');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not select the elements via the "red" and "green" classes and then  add and remove the alternate classes as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred to the solution for toggling class animation here : [ToggleClass animate jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179238/toggleclass-animate-jquery). You should change your `colorChange` function to something like this :

```
function colorChange() {
    $( 'h1 > span' ).toggleClass( "red green", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
}
```

And make sure you build the `span`s at the beginning with alternative classes to each item (use one of your `redGreen()` or `greenRed()` function for the first time only).

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esuxzjfg/)

> **You need to include [jQuery UI](https://api.jqueryui.com/) to have the effect.**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the fade effect by using `setTimeout`.

See the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/faFyT8xq1zGG8cMAxgrg?p=preview)