# Dynamically change the background of a parent when hovering over a child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I may have a dumb question but I just can't figure it out:

I've got 3 columns, and I want to change the background of their parent when I hover over each of them with different background.

I am using this code:

```
$('#first-col').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('first-pic');
})

$('#second-col').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('second-pic');
})

$('#third-col').hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('third-pic');
})
```

And it works great! Now the question part: Is there any way to make it change smoother?

I tried applying

```
transition: background 0.5s linear
```

to the parent but it doesn't do anything. Is there any other way of doing something about it?

Comment: Should works, check it http://jsfiddle.net/6cpds7ga/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ToggleClass animate jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179238/toggleclass-animate-jquery)

Comment: @DrKey it is working when i apply it on the element i'm hovering. But not when i apply it to the parent which is the one changing background...

Comment: @vuchke should works anyway http://jsfiddle.net/6cpds7ga/1/

Comment: It might help to pre-load the background images and transition the `backgound-image` property instead. You could also try transitioning the transparency of the background. Also, shouldn't you remove the other classes when you hover over a new child?