# jQuery toggle between two classes, show and hide

Tags: jquery

I have two classes:

```
<div class="currentWeather"></div>
<div class="weeklyWeather"></div>
```

I am trying to toggle between them so every 10 seconds it will show one of these classes and hide the other and so on.

```
setInterval(function(){

$(".currentWeather, .weeklyWeather").toggleClass("currentWeather weeklyWeather");

}, 3000);
```

But this just switches the class names....Is toggle not what I am looking for?

Comment: You could add another class in css which changes the display to none and then add and remove it from the specific div when setInterval elapses

Comment: `$(".currentWeather, .weeklyWeather").toggleClass("show");` like this?

Comment: That won't work, it adds show to both classes...do you have an example @RyanWilson

Comment: Added as answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//CSS Class:

.mask{
    display: none;
}

//setInterval callback function to add and remove mask class
setInterval(function(){
   //You can check if the element has the class with .hasClass
   if($('.currentWeather').hasClass('mask'){
       $('.currentWeather').removeClass('mask');
       $('.weeklyWeather').addClass('mask');
   }else{
        $('.currentWeather').addClass('mask');
        $('.weeklyWeather').removeClass('mask');
   }

   //Or you can just .toggleClass
    $('.currentWeather').toggleClass('mask');
    $('.weeklyWeather').toggleClass('mask');

}, 3000);

//And your HTML would have to have one of these divs with class mask initially
```

> ```
>    <div class="currentWeather"></div>
>    <div class="weeklyWeather mask"></div>
> ```

Comment: why not just use `toggleClass` for both and remove the `if` statement?

Comment: Would toggleClass have a smoother transition?

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski I'm just used to coding it that way, I added to my answer to reflect the `.toggleClass()` way of doing it, but I'm pretty sure that `.toggleClass()` is doing the same thing I am doing in my `if - else`

Comment: @RyanWilson Agreed, I was just wondering if there was a specific reason for not using it. It looks better too imo ;)

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski I just like to make things harder on myself, old habits, lol

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That's another option as well. Great part about programming, there is typically more than one way to accomplish a goal.

Comment: @RyanWilson tbh I just found out about toggleClass.....wish I heard about it sooner

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski Yeah, I knew about it, I just forget about some methods if I don't use them enough. That's what happens when you start getting old. :P

Comment: How would I add a transition to this?

Comment: @user979331 Please see this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179238/toggleclass-animate-jquery), IMO, Dario's answer will be most helpful