# Why this animate display none to block not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Why this animate display none to block not working ?

First code look like this, and it's work good

```
$(".box_outer").stop().animate({top: '25px' , opacity: 1}, 100);
```

When i add `display: none;` to class `box_outer` and add `, display: 'block'`

My function animate not work , how can i do that ?

```
$(".box_outer").stop().animate({top: '25px' , display: 'block' , opacity: 1}, 100);
```

Comment: You can't animate `display:none` as far as i know....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animation CSS3: display + opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449933/animation-css3-display-opacity)

Answer (score 0):

The [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method works with only properties with numerical values, `display` is not 1 of them so try

```
$(".box_outer").stop().show().animate({top: '25px', opacity: 1}, 100);
```

or if you want to animate the display also, set the height to 0 then use `height: 'show'` as an animation property

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate `display` See this article for a workaround

http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/

Live Demo: http://jsbin.com/iZUGaKI/1/

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you cant animate display property but you can use show() hide() or fadeIn() fadeOut() for the same purpose and they will work well with display:none

```
$(".box_outer").show(100);
```

OR

```
$(".box_outer").fadeIn(100);
```