# I can't seem to disable the scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to disable the scroll bar on page1 but not page2. I have tried many things such as overflow: hidden; or adjusting the height but I have had no luck.

Here is the JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/27fJW/94](http://jsfiddle.net/27fJW/94)

**JS :**

```
YUI().use('transition', 'node-event-delegate', function (Y) {
    var begin = Y.one('#begin');

    function toggle(e) {
        closeIt(e);
        start();
    }

    function start() {
        var node2 = Y.one("#page2");
        node2.replaceClass('invis', 'fade-in-effect');
    }

    function closeIt(e) {
        var node1 = Y.one('#page1');
        node1.hide(true);
    }

    begin.on('click', toggle);
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.invis {

    z-index: -1;

    opacity:0;

}

#page2 {

    position:absolute;

    top:10px;

    left:10px;

}

.fade-in-effect {

    opacity: 1;

    transition: opacity 4s linear;

}
```

**HTML :**

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="page1">This is Page 1
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="start()" id="begin">ClickMe</a>

</div>
<div id="page2" class="invis">This is Page 2 content
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="page1">This is Page 1
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="start()" id="begin">ClickMe</a>

</div>
<div id="page2" class="invis">This is Page 2 content
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>content
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.invis {

    z-index: -1;

    opacity:0;

}

#page2 {

    position:absolute;

    top:10px;

    left:10px;

}

.fade-in-effect {

    opacity: 1;

    transition: opacity 4s linear;

}
```

Javascript

```
YUI().use('transition', 'node-event-delegate', function (Y) {
    var begin = Y.one('#begin');

    function toggle(e) {
        closeIt(e);
        start();
    }

    function start() {
        var node2 = Y.one("#page2");
        node2.replaceClass('invis', 'fade-in-effect');
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }

    function closeIt(e) {
        var node1 = Y.one('#page1');
        node1.hide(true);
    }

    begin.on('click', toggle);
});
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1tzmk6h/)

Comment: Beat me to it, props for same solution though :)

Answer (score 1):

First we hide the overflow, once you go to page 2 you reenable overflow. Updated JS fiddle.

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27fJW/119/)

Another option for display/fade mechanisms is CSS3 Keyframes, and I'd say they are preferred since they are hardware accelerated and also remove some complexity from the general implementation. See here: [Animation CSS3: display + opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449933/animation-css3-display-opacity)

Comment: page2 isn't actually fading in there, it just seems like it since page1 fades out.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick for me in your JSFiddle:

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It disables the scrollbar for page2 also. I don't want that.

Comment: Then put a container around page1 and add a class to it and use the CSS I provided on said class.

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/27fJW/117/ because that isn't working.

Comment: page1 has a very small height so your solution won't work @LansanaCamara. The overflow occurs from page2, restricting page1 does not influence the underlying cause