# CSS opacity ignores transition time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**My solution:**
I changed the `display` styles to `visibility` styles because this solution suited my webpage best. Many other solutions can be found by Googling "*display block overrides animation*". The accepted answer is the one that gave me the keywords so I could use Google.

---

**Original post:**

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6bz4jzq/)

I've made `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions to animate the opacity using CSS animations rather than JQuery animations.
Clicking on the image should make a popup fade in and the image fade out over 300ms.
Clicking anywhere in the body should make the popup fade out and the image fade in over 300ms.

**At the moment the fadeOut works, but fadeIn seems to ignore the transition time, and instantly appears.** Why isn't fadeIn working?

JavaScript:

```
function fadeIn(elem) {
    elem.css("display", "block");
    elem.css("opacity", 1);
}

function fadeOut(elem) {
    elem.css("opacity", 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.css("display", "none");
    }, 300);
}

$("body").on("click", function(ev) {
      if (ev.target != $("#btn")[0] && $("#popup").is(":visible")) {
        fadeIn($("#btn"));
        fadeOut($("#popup"));
    }
});

$("#btn").on("click", function(ev) {
    fadeIn($("#popup"));
    fadeOut($("#btn"));
});
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    color: red;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 1em;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you use `display: block`/`display: none`, and when removed, it works

```js
  function fadeIn(elem) {
  /*
    elem.css("display", "block");
  */    
    elem.css("opacity", 1);
  }

  function fadeOut(elem) {
    elem.css("opacity", 0);
    /*
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.css("display", "none");
    }, 1300);
    */
  }

  $("body").on("click", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target != $("#btn")[0] && $("#popup").is(":visible")) {
      fadeIn($("#btn"));
      fadeOut($("#popup"));
    }
  });

  $("#btn").on("click", function(ev) {
    fadeIn($("#popup"));
    fadeOut($("#btn"));
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vw;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: 1.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 1em;
  transition: 1.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="btn" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://new.matt.cat/scipad-app/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  <p>
    click here to close popup
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why `display` affects it like this? Shouldn't it start the animation *after* the `display: block` is set?

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt It is how `display: block` works, so when you set `elem.css("display", "block");` it simply overrides the animation. What you could do, is to add a timeout for that as well, as what is needed is to force the browser to redraw that area. Here is a post describing this some more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac

Comment: Is this JQuery being "helpful"? I seem to remember setting it through JavaScript (`elem.style.display = "block"`) doesn't do this? Maybe I remember incorrectly.

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt Nope, does not matter which you use...see previous comments link

Comment: Thanks, didn't see the link, I did find this post though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191375/6595777

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt That is another way, if you really need `display: block`. 1:  Have you tested it cross browsers ? .... 2: Why do you need `display: block`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed `display` to `visibility` and it works fine for me (the absolute positions mean that it doesn't interfere with the page flow)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try

`transition: opacity 0.3s;`

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```js
  function fadeIn(elem) {
    elem.css("display", "block");
    elem.css("opacity", 1);
  }

  function fadeOut(elem) {
    elem.css("opacity", 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      elem.css("display", "none");
    }, 300);
  }

  $("body").on("click", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target != $("#btn")[0] && $("#popup").is(":visible")) {
      fadeIn($("#btn"));
      fadeOut($("#popup"));
    }
  });

  $("#btn").on("click", function(ev) {
    fadeIn($("#popup"));
    fadeOut($("#btn"));
  });
```

```css
body {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vw;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 1em;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="btn" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://new.matt.cat/scipad-app/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  <p>
    click here to close popup
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm out at the moment, but testing in my fiddle it doesn't seem to change

Comment: Yea, I missed the display none/block that @LGSon picked up. That said, probably still not a bad idea to stick with standards as transitions (based off spec) should be `transition: property time` and you can use `all` for property which will animate any animatable property.