# Button behind text only on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a very simple quiz like this one:

https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/

I tried to make it more responsive and added this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

It worked fine but when I add a long text on the alternatives of each question, the button "Next Question" stay behind the text, only on mobile (iphone 6, safari).

I tried to add a z-index: 1000; and nothing changed:

```
button{
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #279;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` in addition to a `z-index` (z-index only applies to non-statically positioned elements).

Comment: After position: relative the text is behind the button, but I cannot read the text. How can I force the button to stay under the text (I mean after the text)?

Comment: Check my answer @Rodrick - Should fix your issue :)

Comment: Thanks @Xoog it works. Could yo give me a hand with the fade effect? I added the CSS from Chris's answer from the link mentioned. Should I do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's a few things wrong here.  As said above you need to remove the height from `.quiz-container` and remove the absolute positioning from `.slide`.

What I would suggest is that you add `display: none;` to `slide` then your active style to `display:block` - this will correctly display the button where it should be. With that said, you will lose the fade effect. You'd need to add [this CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449933/animation-css3-display-opacity) to get it back. Hope this helps!

```
.quiz-container {
position: relative;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.slide {
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
display: none;
}

.active-slide {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `position: absolute` to your quizz questions, so they will ignore the space of every element you set in HTML. 
 A large `z-index` will only put an element above another, that's the why you see the quizz questions above the button. 
The problem will be solved if you increment the height of `quiz-container` on mobile screen (try use `@media screen`).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

I recomend you to find another way to put your questions at the top of page instead using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

The problem really is that your quiz-container div has a fixed height of 200px, and you can't make it fluid because your slides have position:absolute, which removes them from the flow and prevents the parent growing in height accordingly.

So you need to re-think how to go about this.

An interesting approach would be to use flexbox, controlling which slide to show with the `order` property.

```
.quiz-container {
    margin-top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#quiz{
    display: flex;
}
.slide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
/*gives each slide 100% width and prevents it from growing or shrinking*/
    flex: 0 0 100%; 
}

.active-slide {
    opacity: 1;
    /*sets the order to -1, so it's positioned before all other flex-items*/
    order: -1;
}
```